# quasinilpotence and finite spectrum II

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let A be a quasinilpotent operator on a Hilbert space and let every
operator of the algebra generated by $A$ and $A^{*}$ have finite
spectrum. Does then follow, that A is nilpotent ?

See also [quasinilpotence and finite spectrum](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77177/quasinilpotence-and-finite-spectrum) 
and [Finite-dimensional subalgebras of $C^\star$-algebras](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35207/finite-dimensional-subalgebras-of-c-star-algebras)

Comment: Do you mean the (norm-)closed algebra generated by $A$ and $A*$? 

Comment: @Yemon Choi : no, not the norm-closed algebra.
I mean the non-commutative polynomials in A and $A^{*}$ .